# What is the Wildfly infinispan web cache container for?

Tags: caching, wildfly, infinispan, infinispan-9, wildfly-12

I'm using Wildfly 12.

The default configuration of the infinispan subsystem defines a cache-container named "web". I tried to find out why this container is defined and who uses it, but could not find any explanation in the documentation or anywhere on google so far.

**standalone-full-ha-custom.xml:**

```
<cache-container name="web" default-cache="dist" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
    <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
    <distributed-cache name="dist">
        <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
        <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
        <file-store/>
    </distributed-cache>
</cache-container>
```

What kind of data is stored in this cache and which components need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `web` cache container is used for storing HTTP session information. WildFly's [High Availability Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/High+Availability+Guide) contains information on all clustered services.